# MKMapview delegate never called even with set delegate

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, xcode4.2, mkmapviewdelegate

I have a UIView that integrate a scrollview.  Inside the scrollview I have a map where a user need to move a pin.  I'm gonna reuse the location of pin later.

I'm setting strong reference and setting delegate ( both design and code) for the map.   I'm able to see the pin created but to have custom icon and possibility to set it draggable, I have implement the mapView( viewFor MKAnnotation

This seems to be never called and I'm not getting why.

I also try to get another delegate as didfinishloading to understand if problem is related to the mkannotation but also this one is never been called.

```c
import Foundation
import Firebase
import MapKit
import UIKit


public class Setup: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate{


    var ChargePointID = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var chargepointIDLabel: UILabel!


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var pin: customPin!
    //setting up variables
    //pricing textfield and slider
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceSlider: UISlider!


    @IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         chargepointIDLabel.text = ChargePointID
        self.map.delegate = self
        self.map.mapType = .hybrid
        // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        //create liocation relative to user
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

        //centering map to user location
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005))
        self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        //creating a pin of type custompin
        pin = customPin(pinTitle: ChargePointID, pinSubTitle: "", location: location)

        map.addAnnotation(pin)


    }

    private func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }



    private func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        print("annotation title == \(String(describing: view.annotation?.title!))")
    }


    private func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        print("ok")
        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customannotation")
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named:"setuppin")
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        return annotationView

    }

    func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
print(" map has finished")
    }


    private func map(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        print("ok")
        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "customannotation")
        annotationView.image = UIImage(named:"setuppin")
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true
        return annotationView

    }







}

class customPin: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?

    init(pinTitle:String, pinSubTitle:String, location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = pinTitle
        self.subtitle = pinSubTitle
        self.coordinate = location
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`private` is not necessary. Replace

```
private func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
```

with

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
```

Answer (score 0):

this was cause Xcode was raising this warning

instance method 'mapView(*:viewFor:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'mapView(*:viewFor:)' of protocol 'MKMapViewDelegate'

and suggest make it private as fix. btw even without private not raise anything

Answer (score 0):

DAMN!!!!!

I solved it....       the warning was cause my class was declared ad public and delegate need to be too.

I removed the public statement from my class and everything start to work .

so problem in end was main class declared as public !